# JSON Response output is not updated on single click event

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

I am trying to build a java online compiler web app using  django.
but every time I submit my code through AJAX call the new code is posted successfully to view.py but the JSON response object is still the previous one.

```
def code1(request):

    response_data={}

    **codet=request.POST.get("code","")** # getting the code text from Ajax req

    **output=code(codet)** #sending code for execution


    response_data['result']="Successful" #storing in response
    response_data['message']=output 

    **return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")**

def code(code_text):
    return execute(code_text)

def execute(code_text):

    filename_code=open('Main.java','w+') #creating file
    filename_code.flush()
    f1 = code_text.split("\n") # splitting code line by line
    for i in f1:
        filename_code.write(i+"\n") #writing code line by line
    filename_code.close() #closing file
    time.sleep(2) #giving wait
    **compile_java(filename_code)** 
#compiling file (Note: I am not using the file passed in compile_java)
    **return execute_java(filename_code,input**) #running java file


def compile_java(java_file):
   proc = subprocess.Popen('javac Main.java', shell=True) 

def execute_java(java_file, stdin):
    #java_class,ext = os.path.splitext(java_file)
    cmd = ['java ', 'Main']
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
    stdout,stderr = proc.communicate(stdin)
    stdoutstr= str(stdout,'utf-8')

    **

 1. return stdoutstr

**
```

Actually the previous json response is being sent for current code(codet)